# Sending bus signal using analysis port

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am using UVM to test very simple interface and now facing with “corner-case” issue.
So I need to send logic[0:7] signal from output monitor to scoreboard.
This is part of the code:

```
class outputMonitor extends uvm_monitor;
..
   logic [7:0] lcdCmd;    
uvm_analysis_port #(logic) sendPrt;

task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
    forever
    begin
         sendPrt.write(lcdCmd)   ;    
    end
endtask
endclass

class scoreboard extends uvm_subscriber #(logic);
`uvm_component_utils(scoreboard)

function void write (logic t);
    $display("%t: scoreboard: ###########  calling write function-- data=%b", $time, t);

endfunction
endclass
```

During simulation I see that only the last bit of lcdCmd is transferred to scorebaord. Is there a way to transfer the whole bus data using ports?

Of course I can create struct or transaction, put the lcdCmd there and then send the struct. But why I cannot just send the bus?

Thanks
Hayk

Answer (score 2):

In your code you did a simple mistake.Like...

- Pass type argument of analysis fifo as only logic in stand of logic[7:0] vector.
- Same thing is applicable for subscriber class parameter and also at write implementation function argument.
- See the code which you need to change.

```
class outputMonitor extends uvm_monitor;
`uvm_component_utils(outputMonitor)

  logic [7:0] lcdCmd;    
  uvm_analysis_port #(logic[7:0]) sendPrt;

  task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
    forever
    begin
      sendPrt.write(lcdCmd);    
    end
  endtask

endclass

class scoreboard extends uvm_subscriber #(logic[7:0]);
`uvm_component_utils(scoreboard)

  function void write (logic [7:0] t);
    $display("%t: scoreboard: ###########  calling write function-- data=%b", $time, t);
  endfunction

endclass
```